# Are there specific cache tags which get reset on user login?

Tags: caching

**Scenario**

I'd like to invalidate a set of caches based on user id upon user login. I'd like to avoid creating new tags, and limit new code as much as possible. Presumably the way to do this is with cache tags.

The specific use case is to cache a user-specific web service response, per user, for the duration of a user session.

Are there any existing cache tags (or something to similar effect) which are invalidated upon successful user login, so that I don't have to implement `hook_user_login()` to manually invalidate the cache?

Comment: If you want to invalidate some caches, surely you'll already know what those are? Why would you be creating cache tags? What are you caching?

Comment: This should not be done by invalidating cache tags, instead <The_thing_I_want_to_create> should add the current user as cache context. see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts

Comment: @Clive I'm caching some custom user data from a 3rd party service. I'm hoping _not_ to have to define several other hooks or event subscribers to explicitly clear those caches. If there are existing instances of cache invalidation that I can use, by way of cache tags, that will save me some work.

Comment: @Hudri i don't see a way to use cache context with a CacheBackendInterface, only cache tags.

Comment: But unless these cache tags are already on the content you're caching, that won't do anything. And if they are already on it, you'll already know that they're there, because it's custom code and you put them there, right?

Comment: Yes. My question is whether there are tags I can use which get invalidated on user login. So that I don't have to create a hook_user_login and do it myself.

Comment: But what render arrays are you attaching these tags to? Why not just add the user context to them instead?

Comment: There is no render content. I'm calling CacheBackendInterface::set to cache response data from a 3rd party webservice request.

Comment: Oh ok. By the looks of it, no, core doesn't invalidate any tags upon login

Comment: Does login not invoke `User::save()` to update the value for "last login"?

Comment: No it goes straight into the database ([`UserStorage::updateLastLoginTimestamp()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserStorage.php/function/UserStorage%3A%3AupdateLastLoginTimestamp/8.6.x)), and resets the cache by cid

Comment: @aaronbauman I've not used this personally, but sounds like your use case: [PrivateTempStore](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21PrivateTempStore.php/class/PrivateTempStore/8.2.x)

Comment: Cache context can be applied to the page or block you're outputting ur result.

Answer (score 1):

No, there aren't any cache tags invalidated upon login. And even if there were, they wouldn't be tied to your cache. Instead, you should act on hook_user_login(), and expire the cache yourself.

Cache invalidation isn't really something you would piggy back onto something non-relevant. Rather, you set up elements with cache tags/contexts etc, and then if necessary you add your own cache invalidation on relevant events.